# Inserting calculations of the std::partial_sum into the empty vector (c++17)

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17

I am pretty new to the C++ and now I am experimenting with `std::partial_sum` algorithm.

I want to calculate partial sum of existing vector and insert result into a new `vector`.

I tried with this code to do this:

```
vector<double> earnings = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
vector<double> temp;
std::partial_sum(earnings.begin() + 1, earnings.begin() + 3,  temp.begin())
```

But I got a segmentation fault. But with another approach it worked:

```
vector<double> earnings = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
vector<double> temp;
std::partial_sum(earnings.begin() + 1, earnings.begin() + 3,  std::back_inserter(temp))
```

Can you explain me why did the last one worked, but first didn't?

Comment: In the 1st example, `temp` is empty and stays that way. In the 2nd the `std::back_inserter` is adding elements to the `vector` (via `push_back`) and enlarging it.

Comment: `temp` is empty so you can't write into it without using `push_back`

Comment: The first example expects the vector to have at least the required number of elements beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::partial_sum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum) is expecting a valid iterator to be used to fill the result (and if the result contains of multiple elements, the iterator should be such that you can increment according to the number of elements to fill).

In your 1st case, `temp` is empty and stays that way. The iterator `temp.begin()` does not refer to any valid element to fill.

In your 2nd case, you use [`std::back_interter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), which constructs a [`std::back_insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator). This iterator is calling `push_back` on the `vector` to add new elements and is therefore a valid iterator for `std::partial_sum` to fill the `vector`.